# tar error message: "stdin: not in gzip format"

Tags: ubuntu, tar

I'm having difficulty with `tar` on a headless Ubuntu Server 12:

```
ubuntu@domU-12-31-39-02-C0-98:~$ wget -o dropbox.tar.gz "http://www.dropbox.com/download?plat=lnx.x86"
ubuntu@domU-12-31-39-02-C0-98:~$ tar -xzvf dropbox.tar.gz

gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

If I download the file on Windows, I can unpack it with 7-zip just fine. What am I doing wrong with `tar`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `-o` option of `wget` specifies where to put the log file.

You'll find that your `dropbox.tar.gz` is a plain text file containing diagnostic messages from `wget`.

Try this:

```
wget -O dropbox.tar.gz "http://www.dropbox.com/download?plat=lnx.x86"
```